# How ca I run Typescript Unit test case locally & on cloudbees?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript

I have created one app in typescript, now I want to write some unit case for that app.

Q.1 : how can I write unit test cases for typescript.

Q.2 : I want to deploy that app on cloudbees for continuous integration purpose, but I want to run those unit test cases on cloudbees, so what should I need to do for that?